# Recovering a badly sysprepped Windows Server 2012 R2 image

Tags: azure, sysprep

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 image in Azure. It has been curated by a number of people in my org. A lot of software installed and configured etc.

The VM it was created from was then sysprepped without the `/generalize` parameter.

Now if we create machines from this image the new machines all have the same hostname etc. If we further make changes to a machine created from this image, and then sysprep with the `/generalize` flag, all the new machines from the second image still miss out on a new machine name from the `unattend.xml` injected by Windows Azure on machine creation.

How do we recover our image so that the `unattend.xml` from Azure will run on bootup so our machines get a new name?

thanks!

Comment: I hazard a guess that the sysprep may not have succeeded. Can you make sure you sysprep as shown in http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-capture-image-windows-server/ ? Make sure you use generalize, oobe and shutdown options.

Comment: I'd probably agree with you. i think it sysprepped fine, but it wasn't generalized. the problems only occur in the `generalized` sysprep of an vm sysprepped *without* being `generalized`